# Initialize axios interceptors before any api request is made in the application

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have a custom hook that initializes the axios interceptors and returns if there's any error message for api calls. This hook is used in the layout page and display the error in any api request in a central location. If I use the `useEffect` in the layout page, it gets called after the child page's `useEffect`.

Right now, I am using `useLayoutEffect` to do this, but want to know if there's any standard way to achieve this.

I am using browser router v6 so looked into `loader` function but I need to be able to retrieve the error message to display in layout page.